# Replace text literally without regular expression in Emacs evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In vim, I could use `:%sno/[abt]//g` to remove all text of "[abt]" literally (as explained [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic)).

I tried the same command in `evil-mode`, but it complains it doesn't understand the `sno` command, so how can I do the same thing in `evil-mode`?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, `evil` does not (yet?) support the "magic/no magic" regexp options (actually, it only does a smallish subset of `ex` functionality<s>, so I don't think `%` will work either</s>).  As @Ehvince's answer suggests, the standard Emacs way to do the replace is with `query-replace` or `query-replace-regexp`.  If you'd like to stick to `evil`, just escape the square brackets with a backslash:

```
:s/\[abt\]//g
```

*NB*: backslash escapes in Emacs often bite people coming from other environments or programming languages; have a look at [the bottom of this manual node on the backslash](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special) for more information.

Comment: Good to know!  `%` is a nice feature; answer corrected to strikethrough the offending passage.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the emacs command `query-replace` bound to `M-%`:

```
M-% [abt] RET <nothing> RET
```

and then approve each occurence with `y` or all with `!`.

The doc is at `C-h f query-replace`.

`query-replace-regexp` is bound to `C-M-%`.